# ExtJS and jQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-interface, extjs

I've seen some posts where jQuery has been favored vs ExtJS. I haven't looked at jQuery in detail, but from what I read so far, jQuery doesn't provide the kind of UI which comes with ExtJS. Am I correct? Why would some of you prefer jQuery in ASP.NET?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two schools of javascript frameworks, ones that focus on widgets (Yui, ext, etc) , and ones that focus on behavior (jquery, prototype, moo, etc)

JQuery just makes life easier to build dynamic, sexy sites. If you are just doing system.draggy.droppy asp development, you can ignore both, since you probably aren't really touching javascript at all. But if you do use javascript, it is worth your time to learn one of the frameworks that are out there, and jquery is currently the most popular.

Comment: Where dows ExtJS fits in? widgets (i think) or behaviour? Can I use both in a project?

Comment: ExtJS is more for widgets, it is basically winforms for javascript. You can easily use both, they have complementary functionality. 

if you need ext for .net, I would suggest checking out the coolite project http://www.coolite.com/, which is .net wrappers for ext.

Answer (score 8):

Why not use both?  ExtJS does allow you to use jQuery as well.  In fact, you can easily configure ExtJS to use jQuery for its core functionality.  I've done this before and it works quite well.

This way you can happily use the best of both worlds.

http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=29702&highlight=jquery

Answer (score 4):

In fact Ext provides a one-stop-shop.

It has a solid foundation which provides behaviour. Event pub/sub, effects, DOM manipulation etc. And it can provide these through its own standalone foundation, OR by wrapping a foundation library of your choice (like jQuery)

And then on TOP of that cross-library foundation layer, it provides a unified set of Components all stemming from one Component base class. It provides managed screen layout which responds to browser geometry changes, and managed lifecycle management of the Components.

There's nothing out there like it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does have a widgets library - it's fairly new, but pretty cool. It can only get better!
[jQuery UI](http://ui.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

iam experienced on extjs and fresher for jquery.jquery is very light weight than extjs.

### About JQUERY:

easy to use, fast, great DOM manipulation, good effects. Great window.onLoad handler.

### About EXTJS:

Ivery very extensive, great DOM manipulation, solid effects. The fastest to get things done when puzzling out on the commandline.